# passthru real request with pretender.js

Tags: javascript, testing, pretender.js

I am trying to pass through to a real webservice in an acceptance test in my project.  Pretender intercepts all xhr request so i'm trying to tell it to pass through for example.com

according to the [docs](https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender#pass-through) i should be able to do this.

```
var server = new Pretender(function(){
  this.get('https://www.example.com/:catchall', this.passthrough);
});
```

or this

```
var server = new Pretender();
server.get('https://www.example.com', server.passthrough);
```

but I get this in my console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Pretender intercepted GET
>   https://www.example.com/foo/bar but encountered an error:
>   handler.handler is not a function(…)

because

handler.handler is server.passthrough 
and server.passthrough is an object?

```
> server.passthrough 
 Object {numberOfCalls: 1, async: undefined}
```

The test passes in isolation but fails when i run the full suite on the console with npm test.  it also passes in the browser.  I think i have either a race condition.